# How do you disable touchpad in Ubuntu 14.04LTS?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

How do I disable the touchpad while using bluetooth mouse?

The Synaptic(k)s touchpad app does not appear to be available in the software center for 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal with CTRL + ALT + T then;

copy and paste this `synclient TouchpadOff=1` and hit enter.

to enable the touchpad again, copy and paste this `synclient TouchpadOff=0` and hit enter.